# Laravel 5.2 : Relationship - please advise

Tags: laravel-5

User Model

```
| Field           | Type          
+-----------------+-----------------
id              | int(10) unsigned | NO  
name            | varchar(255)     | NO  
email           | varchar(255)     | NO
```

Club Model

```
 Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| user_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| name       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
```

Club member Model

```
+------------+------------------+------
Field      | Type             
id         | int(11)          
club_id    | int(10)           
user_id    | int(10)
status     | varchar(20)
```

How to make relationship using laravel?
I assume that User has many club .

in **User Model**

```
`public function clubs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Club');
}`
```

Club has many members(users). I created ClubMember model

**how to declare the relation in clubMember model?** and **club  member belongs to club and user **

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a many to many relationship to me. Your "Club member Model" table is the pivot table.

You can add this relation to your user model:

```
public function clubs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Club', 'PIVOT TABLE NAME');
}
```

and this to your club model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'PIVOT TABLE NAME');
}
```

Change PIVOT TABLE NAME to the name of your table. Laravel assumes that it is named "club_user". If you name it like this, you dont need to add the second parameter.

Check the Laravel documentation for more information on many to many relationships.